# Surround every matching word inside XML tag with braces

Tags: regex

I have html string like the following:

```
<whatevertag do-not-change-this="word" or-this-word="">
  these words should be replaced with a word inside braces,
  and also the same word thing for
  <whatevertag>
      the nested tags that has the word
  </whatevertag>
</whatevertag>
```

I'm trying to make the output like this:

```
<whatevertag do-not-change-this="word" or-this-word="">
  these {word}s should be replaced with a {word} inside braces,
  and also the same {word} thing for
  <whatevertag>
      the nested tags that has the {word}
  </whatevertag>
</whatevertag>
```

I've tried this expression `(>[^>]*?)(word)([^<]*?<)` and for the substitution I've used `$1{$2}$3`.. surprisingly (at least for me) it only worked for the first matches only, the output was:

```
<whatevertag do-not-change-this="word" or-this-word="">
    these {word}s should be replaced with a word inside braces,
    and also the same word thing for
    <whatevertag>
        the nested tags that has the {word}
    </whatevertag>
</whatevertag>
```

why this is happening. and how can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your regex is unsuccessfull is:

```
(>[^>]*?)                  # read '>', then lazily any character except '>'
(word)                     # until you encounter 'word'
([^<]*?<)                  # then lazily read any character except '<' until you find a '<'
```

So, whenever you've captured 'word' your regex reads until the first '<'. That's why the second 'word' is not captured.

What you could use is:

```
(?:(?!word).)+(word)
```

Explanation:

```
(?:                         # Do not capture
(?!word).)+                 # Negative lookahead for word. Read 1 char
(word)                      # until you find 'word'
```

Look at [example](https://regex101.com/r/ge6XMS/1)

EDIT: Rereading your question you make it clear that you want to capture everything outside of the " tags. Take a look at:
[example 2](https://regex101.com/r/ge6XMS/2)

The regex is:

```
((?!word)[^>])+(word)([^<]+) # read all characters, except 
                             # '>' until you encounter 'word'
                             # read 'word'
                             # capture all following characters, except '<'
```

Comment: there will be a problem if you use parameters in the tags that would have "word" like `<tag some-attribute="word">` I need it to replace only the words inside the tags this is why I'm using the expression i use.. and really i have no idea who minus my question and the heck why?!

Comment: Let me fix an example for that as well. I did not downvote your question. If one downvotes an answer or question, one should give an explanation. IMHO.

Comment: how would be the substitution like? I would be very grateful if you provided it.

Comment: What language? perl?

Comment: you can use it from the link you are using for the example in whatever language I don't mind.